# References from same author order randomly (not by year)

Tags: biblatex, chicago-style, biblatex-chicago

In my bibliography (Chicago Style), references from the same author order not by year but randomly (as it seems). I am using the following specifications:

```
\documentclass[11pt,oneside]{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=chicago-authordate, uniquename=false]{biblatex}
```

Is there a logic that Chicago uses for ordering? Can I Change it to chronological?

Comment: Can you provide a short minimal example that reproduces the seemingly random order (see [I've just been asked to write a minimal example, what is that?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864), [How to write a MWEB (Minimal working example with Bibliography)?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)).

Comment: Please note that to use `biblatex-chicago` you should call it via the wrapper package and not `biblatex` directly. Unless you know exactly what you are doing, `\usepackage[authordate]{biblatex-chicago}` is the better choice.

Comment: Perfect, that solved the ordering. Thanks. However, now I get the following error message (ShareLatex):  

Package biblatex Warning: No "backend" specified, using Biber backend. To use BibTeX, load biblatex with the "backend=bibtex" option.   

And quite a few others telling me about "empty ibidem citations". Can you translate? ;)

Comment: The backend warning can be solved as below. The "empty ibidem citations" warrant a new question with an example that reproduces them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`biblatex-chicago` should be called via its wrapper package, because that makes sure to pass all the right options (amongst them `sorting=cms`) to `biblatex`.

So you would use

```
\usepackage[authordate, backend=biber]{biblatex-chicago}
```